# Multiple has_many through same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Using Rails 5.2.4.2, I have models:

```
Team
  has_many :player_teams
  has_many :players, through: :player_teams

Role
  has_many :player_teams
  has_many :players, through: :player_teams

Player
  has_many :player_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :player_teams
  has_many :roles, through: :player_teams

PlayerTeam
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :role
```

Can't figure out how to add player to team. Is it correct way to add it like I did below or I need to create PlayerTeam instance first with role and team?

```
role = Role.create(...)
team = Team.create(...)
player = Player.create(...)

player.roles << role => Ok
team.players << player => ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: Validation failed: Player teams team must exist
```

**Update 1**

I know that code below and Pierre's is correct, but is there **another** way to add player to team?

```
player_teams = PlayerTeam.create(team: evaluator.team, role: evaluator.player_role)
player.player_teams << player_teams => Ok
```

Say I added role to player

```
player.roles << Role.create()
```

And if I add player to team, is new PlayerTeam instance initiated? How to add player to team without new PlayerTeam instance?

**Update 2**

It seems that if I want to add player to team as I want to

```
team.players << player
```

Than I need set optional: true or separate Role join table to move PlayerTeam’s belongs_to :role to separate model.

Comment: When you create a new player and assign a team or role to that player, the `player_team` instance will be automatically created because you have to go through the `player_team` table to get to the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you are not creating a relation between all of these models.

A good way to do that should be:

```rb
role = Role.new(...)
team = Team.new(...)
player = Player.new(...)

playerTeam = PlayerTeam.new(role: role,
                            team: team,
                            player: player)
```

Moreover, if you want these instances stored into your DB, replace all the `.new` by `.create`. If you do `PlayerTeam.create`, you need first to do `.create` on all other instances, because PlayerTeam will require `role`, `team` and `player` IDs to be saved.